# WIX Multiple DefineConstants defined in MSBuild - problem with proposed solution

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.5, msbuild-4.0

Regarding the answer provided at this link: [Proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506687/defining-multiple-values-in-defineconstants-in-msbuild-element/4280454#4280454)

I tried to use this method in a several ways and I was unable to get it to work. I have double checked that I am running the framework 4 version of msbuild, which I am, and followed the instructions carefully.

My WixValues property looks like this

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixValues>
      OnBuildServer=True;
      DefineConstants=TXT=$(TXT);ProdVersion=$(InstallVersion);
      Configuration=Release;
      Platform=x64;
      SuppressAllWarnings=True;
      APPDATA=$(APPDATA);
    </WixValues>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But somehow the 2nd defineconstant value doesn't get to the command line even though all the other values get there OK.

```
The candle command line from the msbuild log looks like this:
..\WixTools\candle.exe -sw -TXT=TRUE -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*" -d"SolutionDir=*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*" -d"SolutionExt=*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*" -d"SolutionFileName=*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*" -d"SolutionName=*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*" -d"SolutionPath=*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*" -dConfiguration=Release -dOutDir=bin\x64\Release\ -dPlatform=x64 -dProjectDir=C:\Builds\Viper06\InstallSE64wix\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=InstallSE64wix.wixproj -dProjectName=InstallSE64wix -dProjectPath=C:\Builds\Viper06\InstallSE64wix\InstallSE64wix.wixproj -dTargetDir=C:\Builds\Viper06\InstallSE64wix\bin\x64\Release\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=InstallSE64wix.msi -dTargetName=InstallSE64wix -dTargetPath=C:\Builds\Viper06\InstallSE64wix\bin\x64\Release\InstallSE64wix.msi -out obj
```

The MSBuild task looks like this

```
<MSBuild
      Projects="$(SvnWorkingCopy)\InstallSE64wix\InstallSE64wix.wixproj"
      Targets="Rebuild"
      Properties="$([MSBuild]::Unescape($(WixValues)))"
      />
```

Here's the project file entry

```
<DefineConstants>$([MSBuild]::Unescape($(WixValues)))</DefineConstants>
```

Any help from Rory or anyone else who got this to work would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot take credit for this. Found the answer at [wix users](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg26366.html)
Thanks to Alex Ivanoff.

Here's the basic concept.
1st in the wixproj file add the following:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CreateProperty Condition="$(BuildNumber) != ''"
Value="BuildNumber=$(BuildNumber);$(DefineConstants)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Condition="$(RevisionNumber) != ''"
Value="RevisionNumber =$(RevisionNumber);$(DefineConstants)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

2nd in your msbuild task do this:

```
<MSBuild Projects="YourWixProject.wixproj" 
   Properties="BuildNumber=$(VerBuildNumber);RevisionNumber=$(RevisionNumber)" 
/>
```

Note that the Properties aren't standard properties and normally they won't get passed through but in this case they will. Additional standard properties along with the non-standard ones also get transferred correctly.