# msbuild with multiple DefineConstant values, including embedded semicolon

Tags: msbuild

I have an msbuild script which uses the Exec tag to kick off another MSBuild command including a DefineConstants property with multiple values.  Since I have multiple values for that property, I'm using the technique described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506687/passing-multiple-values-to-wix-defineconstants-property-with-msbuild) to call MSBuild.exe directly (not use the MSBuild tag) and enclose the values in quotes.

However, I now need to embed a special symbol into one of those values, which I'm attempting to do using the code `&#175;` (registered trademark ®)

The problem is that the special character code must end in a semicolon, but when I embedded the semicolon, msbuild reads that as a value seperator.  I can seem to find a valid way to escape the semicolon and have it still show up in the end parameter value.

**My question is this:
How can I embed the special char into my build parameter?**

To improve readability, I've moved the value to a variable in my example, but that's not a requirement.

File: TopLevelBuildScript.proj

```
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="BuildWithSpecialChar">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Note: %3B is the escape code for semicolon -->
      <MyProductName Include="Trademarked&amp;#174%3B Product" />
      <OtherProperty Include="foo" />
    </ItemGroup>

   <Exec Command="msbuild.exe subBuildScript.proj /p:DefineConstants=&quot;MyProductName=@(MyProductName);OtherVar=@(foo);AnotherVar=asdf;&quot; " />
    </Target>
  </Project>
```

When executed, the above produces the command line:

```
msbuild.exe subBuildScript.proj /p:DefineConstants="MyProductName=Trademarked&#174; Product;OtherVar=foo;AnotherVar=asdf;"
```

Which ends up defining the constants with the product name split at the semicolon:

```
MyProductName=Trademarked&#174
Product
OtherVar=foo
AnotherVar=asdf
```

Note: I've also tried using %25 for the percent sign:

```
<MyProductName Include="Trademarked&amp;#174%253B Product" />
```

But that gives me:

```
MyProductName=Trademarked&#174B Product
OtherVar=foo  
AnotherVar=asdf
```

**Update**

It turns out the issue wasn't with MSBuild, rather with the way WiX parses parameters (my subBuildScript utilizes WiX).  I didn't consider that, so didn't mention it in my original posting.

Ultimately, I went with a solution based on [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280454/682840):

```
<PropertyGroup>   
  <WixValues>
    <MyProductName>Trademarked® Product<MyProductName>
    <OtherProperty>foo"</OtherProperty>
  </WixValues>
</PropertyGroup>
<MSBuild
    Projects="subProjectScript.proj"
    Properties="Configuration=Release;WixValues=$([MSBuild]::Escape($(WixValues)))"
    Targets="Clean;Rebuild"
    ContinueOnError="false"
    StopOnFirstFailure="true">
</MSBuild>
```

and unescaping the values in subProjectScript.proj as described in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MSBuild files are XML, which you can encode as UTF-8, so you should be able to copy/paste the trademark character directly in the MSBuild script, **without escaping**.

If you can't take that approach, **don't escape the ampersand**.  There are two levels of escaping things in an MSBuild script.  The first is XML-encoding, so that XML-sensitive characters (`<` and `&`) can be used and you'll still have safe XML.  When MSBuild reads in the file, XML-escape sequences get unescaped.  After that process, MSBuild then does its own un-escaping (i.e. `%3B` for semi-colons).

Because you're using `&amp;` at the beginning of your XMl escape sequence, the XML processor is interpreting that as a *literal* ampersand, not the special XML ampersand, which denotes an escape sequence.  Change your `MyProductName` item group's value to be:

```
<MyProductName Include="Trademarked&#174; Product" />
```

Since `MyProductName` appears to be a scalar value, and not a list, I would use a property instead:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyProductName>Trademarked® Product</MyProductName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your `Exec` task you can then use it like this:

```
<Exec Command="msbuild.exe subBuildScript.proj /p:DefineConstants=&quot;MyProductName=$(MyProductName);OtherVar=@(foo);AnotherVar=asdf;&quot; " />
```

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with the way WiX is parsing the properties, but since I didn't mention WiX involvement in my original post, you couldn't have known that.  Your answer appears to correctly address the question as it was posted, so marking it as accepted.